# How to automatically initialize / uninitialize something globally for every thread?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, initialization, delphi-xe2, ado

I have a unit with an `initialization` and `finalization` section. This unit contains a complex object which is instantiated in the `initialization` and destroyed in the `finalization`. However, this object also contains an ADO Connection. That makes it an issue when using this across threads, because ADO is COM, and needs to be initialized for every thread.

This is how I currently handle this global object instance:

```
uses
  ActiveX;
...
initialization
  CoInitialize(nil);
  _MyObject:= TMyObject.Create;
finalization
  _MyObject.Free;
  CoUninitialize;
end.
```

This only works on the main thread. Any other thread wouldn't be able to access it, and will return an exception `CoInitialize has not been called`.

How do I get around this to make this unit thread-safe? I would need a way to hook every creation/destruction of any thread created, and each thread would need to refer to a different instance of this object. But how to go about doing so?

Comment: You want each thread to call CoInitialize? So, make the next logical step and call CoInitialize from each thread.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, as you already say yourself, each thread needs to call `CoInitialize` separately. And in addition, each thread needs to have its own `ADOConnection` too.

I think you need to leave the idea of using the single global object/connection from that unit. Just repeat that object creation and destruction in each thread. When the thread types are different, then you could design a base thread class on top of them. If the object is too big (has overhead with regard to the thread) or does not 'fit' completely in the thread, then split the object design.

For now, your question sounds like just wanting to keep convenience, but if it is really necessary to centralize the ADO connection involvement, then maybe you could implement multi-cast events for the connection events of both main thread and the other threads. Logging in should not be a problem for successive connections: just store the login values and feed them to the threads.

Answer (score 4):

While another design might be a better solution, you can declare _MyObject as `threadvar` to have a separate instance for each thread. In addition you can move the CoInitialize/CoUnitialize into the constructor/destructor of TMyObject.

I cannot give advice on when to create and free these instances as I have no idea how your threads are created and freed.

Comment: [Pointer and Function variables can't be thread variables](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Using_Thread-local_Variables).

Comment: @NGLN That statement is not pertinent. And it's not even true. You can have thread variables that are pointers. You can have thread variables that are procedural types.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Indeed, the RTL/VCL is full of examples where object instances or procedural types are declared as threadvar. There is even a private class threadvar in System.Classes.TThread. Seems the docs are misleading here.

Comment: @David Pity that [another docs page](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Variables#Thread-local_Variables) doesn't mention pointer variables, but may I conclude that each thread instance isn't automatically created and destroyed? I.e. declaring isn't enough: you still have to take care manually?

Comment: @NGLN IIRC threadbare are zero initialised but never leave scope. So they leak unless you explicitly finalise.

Comment: @David Yes, that's what the docs state. Am I correct that OP still has to do `_MyObject:= TMyObject.Create` and `MyObject.Free` within each thread, despite of `_MyObject` being declared as `threadvar`? My point being: Uwe's explanation of the use of `threadvar` could easily be mistaken for _magically_ having a separate object instance within each thread, only by declaring the global variable as `threadvar`. That may sure be true, but I doubt it, hence...

Comment: @NGLN Yes. I suppose the object could potentially be destroyed from a different thread but that would be somewhat perverse.

Comment: @NGLN In my answer I mention the fact that I cannot say where these instances have to be created or freed, as I have not enough information about when the threads are created and freed.